# Problems installing R3.1.1 on Linux CentOS release 6.5 ( check LDFLAGS for paths to Fortran libraries )

Tags: linux, r, centos, installation, fortran

I'm trying to install **R3.1.1** from sources on  CentOS 6.5.

The `.configure` raises the following error

```
(...)
checking whether we can compute C Make dependencies... yes, using $(CC) -MM
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o FILE.lo... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to support OpenMP... -fopenmp
checking how to get verbose linking output from gfortran... -v
checking for Fortran 77 libraries of gfortran...  -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/cm/shared/apps/slurm/14.03.0/lib64/../lib64 -L/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2 -L/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/cm/shared/apps/slurm/14.03.0/lib64/slurm -L/cm/shared/apps/slurm/14.03.0/lib64 -L/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../.. -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath
checking how to get verbose linking output from gcc -std=gnu99... -v
checking for C libraries of gcc -std=gnu99...  -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/cm/shared/apps/slurm/14.03.0/lib64/../lib64 -L/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2 -L/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/cm/shared/apps/slurm/14.03.0/lib64/slurm -L/cm/shared/apps/slurm/14.03.0/lib64 -L/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../.. -lgcc_s
checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... none
checking for Fortran 77 name-mangling scheme... lower case, underscore, no extra underscore
checking whether gfortran appends underscores to external names... yes
checking whether gfortran appends extra underscores to external names... no
checking whether mixed C/Fortran code can be run... configure: WARNING: cannot run mixed C/Fortran code
configure: error: Maybe check LDFLAGS for paths to Fortran libraries?
```

**gfortran** was installed using yum

```
 gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I've no idea what I should put in LDFLAGS to fix that error.

**UDPATE**:

```
# find / -name "libgfor*.so"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libgfortran.so
/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/lib64/libgfortran.so
/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/lib/libgfortran.so
/cm/images/default-image/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libgfortran.so
/cm/images/default-image/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libgfortran.so
```

.

```
# tail config.log 
#define SIZEOF_LONG_LONG 8
#define SIZEOF_DOUBLE 8
#define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 8
#define HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE 1
#define SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE 16
#define F77_FUNC(name,NAME) name ## _
#define F77_FUNC_(name,NAME) name ## _
#define HAVE_F77_UNDERSCORE 1

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: Try to locate `libgfortran.so` in your system and provide the path `-Lthe_path -lgfortran. If that does not halp, try to find more details in the `config.log` (or similar) file what does the configure actually try to do in that check.

Comment: `$ export  LDFLAGS=" -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32   -lgfortran "` and re-run `configure` : raised the same error. The file `config.log` just stops after `#define HAVE_F77_UNDERSCORE 1`

Comment: It is strange that `gfortran` reports version 4.8.2 but the libraries are 4.4.4. Try to locate (by `which`) which gfortran binary you run and where are its libraries. Try running the `locate` command for libgfortran.

Comment: nice finding, I pressed Ctrl-C too early after my 'find': there is another lib under /cm/* . `which gfortran` returns `/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/bin/gfortran`. I set export  `LDFLAGS="  -L/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/lib64 -L/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.8.2/lib  -lgfortran "` and it works now ! Thks! please move your last comment to an answer, so I can validate it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to locate `libgfortran.so` in your system and provide the path `-Lthe_path -lgfortran` or set the respective environment variables. If that does not help, try to find more details in the `config.log` (or similar) file to find out what does the configure actually try to do in that check.

Your gfortran reports it is version `4.8.2` but the libraries are from version `4.4.4`. Try to locate (by `which`) which gfortran binary you run and where are its libraries. Try running the `locate` command for `libgfortran`.